# How to send variables to class inside of Asynctask - Android

Tags: android, string, class, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have an asynctask that gathers comments, usernames, and numbers from a database by using a JSON method inside the doInBackground() method of the Asynctask. These arrays are then converted into strings in the onPostExecute() method. I want these strings to be sent to a class that extends BaseAdapter, how can I send the Strings to another class but still have the BaseAdapter run in the background? Here is my current code,

```
    class CreateCommentLists extends BaseAdapter{
            Context ctx_invitation;
            String[] listComments;
            String[] listNumbers;
            String[] listUsernames;


            public CreateCommentLists(Context ctx_invitation, String[] test1, String[] test2, String[] test3)
            {
                super();
                this.ctx_invitation = ctx_invitation;
                listComments = test1;
                listNumbers = test2;
                listUsernames = test3;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments[position];
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View v = null;
                try
                {
                    String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx_invitation.getSystemService(inflater);
                    v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                    TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
                    TextView NumbersView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
                    TextView usernamesView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);


                    commentView.setText(listComments[position]);
                    NumbersView.setText(listNumbers[position]);
                    usernamesView.setText(listUsernames[position]);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return v;
            }

          }





        final CreateCommentLists mycmlist = new CreateCommentLists(this, test1, test2, test3);




        class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


            } 

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            } 

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {


                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);


                    return json2;



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                try {  
                    if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 



                            JSONArray commentArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
                            String test1[] = new String[commentArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<commentArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                comments[i] = commentArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray numberArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_NUMBER);
                            String test2[] = new String[] numberArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<numberArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                numbers[i] = numberArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray usernameArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_USERNAME);
                            String test3[] = new String[usernameArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<usernameArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                usernames[i] = usernameArray.getString(i);
                            }


                            ListView lstComments = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                            lstComments.setAdapter(mycmlist);








                            }//end if key is == 1
                        else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                        }//end else
                    }//end if
                } //end try

                catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch    
            }
        }


        new loadComments().execute();
```

Here is my logcat

```
07-16 15:21:15.719: W/dalvikvm(19691): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac9228)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at com.example.DashboardActivity$1CreateCommentLists.getCount(DashboardActivity.java:404)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at com.example.DashboardActivity$1loadComments.onPostExecute(DashboardActivity.java:539)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at com.example.DashboardActivity$1loadComments.onPostExecute(DashboardActivity.java:1)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-16 15:21:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(19691):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need the AsyncTask to be inside your BaseAdapter? It seems you could have your Async in your Activity, get whatever you need from your Adapter using some getter methods..and pass those into your Async

Comment: I say this because it will allow you to separate stuff you need to do in the background from your adapter. Let the AsyncTask worry about the background/json stuff, and let your onPostExecute/main thread manipulate the results of that logic

Comment: noo, the async and baseadpater are not inside of eachother. The async gathers Strings and then is suppose to send it to Baseadapter.

Comment: You have an AsyncTask inside your BaseAdapter class. Why is that needed? That's what I'm asking

Comment: Are they both inside of the `Activity`?

Comment: Yes they are both inside the Activity.

Comment: The asynctask gathers comments in the background and then is suppose to send them to the baseadapter

Answer (score 0):

Since they are both inner-classes of the `Activity` then you should be able to make your `ListView` and `Adapter` references member variables then you can call `setAdapter()` on your `ListView` or `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` depending on if you are updating or initially setting it.

If you make this

```
ListView lstComments
```

a member variable of the `Activity` then inner-classes will be able to see it. So when you call

```
  lstComments = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  lstComments.setAdapter(mycmlist);
```

in your `AsyncTask` it should update your list

Comment: WHere would I place the notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: If you are just initially downloading the list and adding to the `Adapter` then you don't need it. That is for if you are updating a list

Comment: Because I did as you said with the ListView and the variables are still not being sent to the Adapter correctly.

Comment: How/where is `mycmlist` being initialized?

Comment: inside of the asynctask, right under where the strings are made, inside onPostExecute()

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Are you getting an error or...?

Comment: Yes, I get an error. The Error says the variables are empty.